# Custom sorting in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select data from a MySQL table sorted in a particular.
For simplicity, let's assume that there are 3 columns:

```
ID    Priority    ValidDate
1     5           2016-12-12
2     5           2016-03-11
3     0           null
4     0           null
5     0           2016-08-01
6     6           2016-12-31
```

What I want is to sort the output as follows:

- if ValidDate > curdate(), show it first order by ValidDate desc (regardless of priority)
- if ValidDate is null or ValidDate < curdate(), order by priority asc

So for the above table, the output should look like:

```
ID    Priority    ValidDate
6     6           2016-12-31
1     5           2016-12-12
5     0           2016-08-01
3     0           null
4     0           null
2     5           2016-12-31
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT id, image, campaignid, priority, sponsored FROM au_hpbanner order by (sponsored > curdate()) desc, (case when sponsored < curdate() then priority end) asc;
```

But it's not working because row ID 2 is still coming after ID 5 although it should be at the bottom.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out both methods work (mine and the Union Select method suggest by C4ud3x). However, both do not account for null values correctly and that's why my query wasn't working in the first place.

Correct version of my solution:

```
SELECT id, image, campaignid, priority, sponsored 
FROM au_hpbanner 
ORDER BY (sponsored > curdate() and sponsored is not null) desc,
         (case when sponsored < curdate() or sponsored is null then priority end) asc;
```

Slightly improved version of C4ud3x's solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT id, image, campaignid, priority, sponsored
    FROM au_hpbanner
    WHERE sponsored > curdate()
    ORDER BY sponsored desc) a
UNION
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT id, image, campaignid, priority, sponsored
    FROM au_hpbanner
    WHERE sponsored < curdate() or sponsored is null
    ORDER BY priority asc) b
```

I'm not sure which of these work better work better in terms of performance. However, if Union Selects require more round-trips to the database, then the first solution would be better, and this is important in my case because I'm dealing with a huge database.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be doing `UNION SELECTs` which would give more control over each of your cases:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT id,
         image,
         campaignid,
         priority,
         sponsored
    FROM au_hpbanner
    WHERE ValidDate > curdate()
    ORDER BY  ValidDate DESC) a
UNION
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT id,
         image,
         campaignid,
         priority,
         sponsored
    FROM au_hpbanner
    WHERE ValidDate < curdate()
    ORDER BY  priority ASC) b
```